# How to set the title of an editor page (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am opening programatically editor pages in eclipse by using:

```
package org.eclipse.ui.ide;
/**
 * Opens an editor on the given object.
 * <p>
 * If the page already has an editor open on the target object then that
 * editor is brought to front; otherwise, a new editor is opened. If
 * <code>activate == true</code> the editor will be activated.
 * <p>
 *
 * @param page
 *            the page in which the editor will be opened
 * @param input
 *            the editor input
 * @param editorId
 *            the id of the editor extension to use
 * @param activate
 *            if <code>true</code> the editor will be activated
 * @return an open editor or <code>null</code> if an external editor was
 *         opened
 * @exception PartInitException
 *                if the editor could not be initialized
 * @see org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPage#openEditor(IEditorInput, String,
 *      boolean)
 */
public static IEditorPart openEditor(IWorkbenchPage page,
        IEditorInput input, String editorId, boolean activate)
        throws PartInitException {
    // sanity checks
    if (page == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    // open the editor on the file
    return page.openEditor(input, editorId, activate);
}
```

So far, so good, I can see the instance of my editor and my data in, but the just created editor page does not have any title, making a bit ugly to see:[image]

So, my question is, ¿How can I set/modify the title of a just created editor?

Thanks for your answers.
Juan

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer, actually it is part of the IStorageEditorInput required to open the editor, it have a member called public String getName() that is used exactly for that propose, bring a name to the tab. In may case, I just returned null....